# Why is the SO community's response so bad for the questions asked out of curiosity?

Tags: discussion

Before moving on, I'd like to share this [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8707ac/no_need_to_tell_me_why/dw9fbvo/?context=3) which describes the issue perfectly:

> Stack Overflow is awful for this. It’s even worse if the basis for your question is curiosity rather than practicality, i.e. “I know it generally isn’t best practice to do x, but is it actually possible?”. Prepare to be swiftly downvoted and for every single answer to be a variation on “you shouldn’t be doing x”.

I had a similar experience before. [I asked a question about simulation of division by zero (knowing that it's mathematically impossible to do so).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170130/using-bitwise-operator-to-divide-by-0-simulation-of-division-by-0)

May be I didn't phrase the question correctly; I was looking for a way to divide two numbers that would run irrespective of the value of divisor. 
Sound stupid, right? Why would I want to do that? 
Well, the answer is I was just curious what's going to happen if I divide by zero? Would it create an infinite loop? Would it cause the JVM to crash? I had so. many. questions.

Why did I get such a bad response from the community? What can I do to avoid such experience in the future?

Comment: You can present your arguments without referring to reddit posts. Whatever you find in reddit or a random blog is not really relevant here.

Comment: From the tour: "Get answers to practical, detailed questions". That's why a question which is not practical gets a bad response.

Comment: @yivi Noted (need more characters).

Comment: "I had so. many. questions"   - Question is now closed as too broad. Isn't that expected?

Comment: From the edit history and the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29170130/timeline) it looks like you managed to confuse people by not being clear about what you wanted. In the comments it seems like you go back and forth over whether you understand that division by 0 is impossible.

Comment: @Patrice I don't understand how asking for a division algorithm is considered too broad?

Comment: The particular question you reference was likely downvoted not because it was a curiosity question, but because it was incredibly difficult to figure out what you actually wanted to do. Your subsequent edits do not really help the matter. They effectively just restate the question of "how can I divide by zero" which is mathematically nonsensical. If you had better specified your goal, maybe it would have received a less hostile response.

Comment: @Tachyon "I don't understand how asking for a division algorithm is considered too broad?" Your question wasn't asking that though.  And if it was, it would be a question trivially answered with a google search, and so wouldn't make a good SO question.

Comment: @Tachyon not what I am saying. You yourself say you had "so.many.questions" about this. This isn't a good approach for Stack. Looking into your question now, I see about 6 different questions, from "can I do this?" to "do I do this with bit operations?" to "how do I do this without bitwise"?.... there are definitely more than one question. If you were asking for a "division algorithm", then I see a potential for it to be drowned in all the other questions in your current post. (and the last question contradicts the title.... so if not too broad, unclear would definitely be a reason to close)

Comment: _May be I didn't phrase the question correctly:_ I just see Edit 1, Edit 2, Edit 3, Another edit, ... - IMHO, don't do that, because it makes your question confusing. Revise your question to clarify what you initially wanted to know. Don't simply add more questions. At best, focus on a single question.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. The "community" responds badly to bad questions, doesn't matter why they were asked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array for an example of a good "curiosity" question.

Comment: IMHO, in my first edit I made pretty much clear that I want to divide by zero and break my machine. However, I'm not going to argue over this. A lot of people here don't want to admit that there's a problem on the other side too.

Comment: @Tachyon: "*I want to divide by zero*" But since division by zero is *mathematically impossible*, the question answers itself: you cannot do an impossible thing because... ***it's impossible***. Even if you happen upon a formula that looks like the impossible thing, that doesn't mean it actually is the impossible thing.

Comment: You didn't ask a question though, you tried to start a discussion and in the process asked several questions, in a series, each changing the actual question in both intent and response. You posed a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Those were the reasons the question was poorly received, of which it should be noted curiosity was not present, as there is no negative response towards curiosity here.

Comment: @NicolBolas *Sigh*...you're doing exactly what the Reddit comment says. Dividing by zero is impossible but creating a program isn't. Here: [Surprise# 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214872/2316543), [Surprise# 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29186306/2316543). Also, you might want to read this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365121/2316543) to understand what I was trying to do.

Comment: @TravisJ I was explaining what I wanted. No one complained in the original thread that I was asking too many questions. The only thing they were complaining about was that my requirement was impossible.

Comment: @Tachyon: I know what you're trying to do. You're trying to create some function `F(x,y)` which results in `x/y` for most values of `x` and `y`, but results in an actual value if `y` is zero. That doesn't change the fact that any such function `F` will *not be division*, and the result of any such `F(x, 0)` cannot be considered to be "dividing by zero".

Comment: @NicolBolas Correct. That's why I used the word **simulation**. Result - I wasn't expecting a number but the program to stop working.

Comment: @Tachyon - Complained? This isn't reddit. They used their votes, they downvoted your post, they voted to close it, and then moved on. The day you posted your set of edits you received your first set of 3 downvotes.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't want to argue anymore; peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is reminiscent of the [uncatchable `ChuckNorrisException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13883166/1079354) in that its scope is more curiosity than practicality.

I feel like [your first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29170130/1) was crystal clear as to what you were looking for:  **is it possible to divide by zero using only bit manipulation?**  Your attempts at "clarification" from there only served to muddle and mangle your question.

The logical answer would be provided in the answers, and your curiosity would be sated.

My gut tells me that you're receiving the kind of feedback that you are because these sorts of questions have a mixed reception.  You can either hit the jackpot with the community and get a *really* good reception, or more typically, be relegated to the "this isn't a good question"-style comments and thus, be vulnerable to downvotes.

Problem is, both your question *and* the `ChuckNorrisException` question are vulnerable to the same problem we have with questions:  **usefulness and lack of research**.

The problem is that *no* amount of actual development work will ever make these questions "useful".  Neither of these things are *useful* in practical, every day programming.  Neither of these things would be good code to see.

Informative, sure; it's informative to know that you cannot bit-shift and wind up dividing by zero.  That's got *some* value to it.  It's also useful to know that you actually *can* throw an exception that can't be caught (but only after doing evil things with the JVM).

Personally speaking, I get *why* your question was downvoted, but I'm not a *fan* of that reasoning.  I would think that your question was interesting, so I probably *wouldn't* upvote it myself, but I also wouldn't downvote it outright, either.

Lastly:

> What can I do to avoid such experience in the future?

The only thing I can say:  **get lucky**.  This happens more often than we like to admit.  There's no tooling or policy to help us ameliorate these kinds of "not entirely practical, but still a useful and otherwise on-topic programming question"-type questions, and until a policy exists, it's going to be at the whim of whomever's looking at the question to decide if they hard downvote it.

Comment: "This happens more often than we like to admit." Heh... the votes on your answer speak for themselves.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah...cause it takes courage to admit that you're wrong.

Answer (score 17):

Read the tooltip for upvotes and downvotes (for questions).

There are three different criteria in there.  First we have research.  So, was  your quest well researched?  Your question appears to be (we'll get back to that one) "what would happen when I run some code that I haven't shown you?"  Which, other problems aside, is a question you can very trivially answer yourself by just *running the code*.  If you want to know what the program does then *run it and find out*.  If you don't understand what happens, or why it happens, then a better question would explain what you did, what happened, what you thought would happen, and a question asking about exactly what what you saw ended up happening (that is, if you couldn't figure it out on your own, after, again spending some time looking into it).

Next we have usefulness, an issue that's more endemic among questions like what you've described, unlike the other two problems which are more specific to your question.  If you honestly can't explain why anyone would ever need to know the answer to the question that you have then that's *quite* the sign that the question isn't useful.  You don't necessarily need to be in the position of actually needing the solution to the question you're asking, but the question is expected to *have* situations where it would be useful to *someone*.  If it doesn't, it's not a useful question.

Finally we have clarity.  Your question just...isn't clear.  It was especially unclear before you started editing it, but while your edits *help*, it's still not particularly clear what you're actually asking.  Even with the edits, the question is still missing a lot of information, but it's also problematic because your edits have edited in like six new questions.   You should be asking *one question* per question.  So while your question is still not clear even after those edits, it's also most certainly too broad.

> What can I do to avoid such experience in the future?

Make sure your questions are well researched, useful, and clear.

Answer (score 13):

When I read a post, I don't care why it was asked. It can be out of curiosity, a problem from the real life, or just a theoretical question.

I do care about the content - Is the question well defined? Is it well written and understandable? Is the post well researched? If the answers are yes, I upvote.

If you want to receive good feedback on your posts, keep them clear, well researched and detailed. We don't judge posts by the reason behind them.

I think your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170130/using-bitwise-operator-to-divide-by-0-simulation-of-division-by-0) is interesting, I didn't downvote it, but I didn't upvote either, maybe because I'm not very familiar with this field.

Comment: _"We don't judge posts by the reason behind them."_ But we can comment on them :P

Comment: @AndréKool We can also downvote, and vote to delete.. but we never judge ;)